# Turn ModPagespeed=off for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, mod-pagespeed

Mod_pagespeed works fine for all browsers but Internet Explorer.

Is there a more efficient way to turn pagespeed off specifically for IE?

I'm doing it by appending  ?ModPagespeed=off to requests made by the detected user agent.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-10]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?ModPagespeed=off [QSA]
```

Comment: are you using the latest builds of mod_pagespeed? they are working on browser issues

Comment: Well, i was using the latest stable. Your comment got me looking, and switching to the latest beta solves the issues AFAICS! thanks a lot!